# $\frac {\partial g} {\partial f}=\frac g f$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, partial-derivative

I found a university excercise where
$$w_n=\sum\limits_{i=n}^N x_i$$
and then, in solution, suddendly this happens:
$$\frac {\partial w_2} {\partial w_1}=\frac {w_2} {w_1}.$$

I don't understant how this happens.

Comment: Some more context is needed.

Comment: @egreg For multiple dependent variables also, if $ y/x $ = const, then with respect to any single arbitrary independent variable, by Quotient Rule we have  $ y'/x' $ = same const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing .. $ \dfrac {w_2} {w_1} $ is a constant with respect to independent variable $x$

Comment: Yes. After some formation, it is true.